# highlight tags not working on index configuration

Tags: algolia

i'm trying to change the highlighting tags from `<em>` to `<strong>` on my index configuration under display (pic related), but the changes are not being applied, am i missing something?

currently I'm passing these as params on the query in order for it to work,

highlightPreTag: "`<strong>`",
highlightPostTag: "`</strong>`",

[current algolia config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6ESr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algolia applies change settings in an asynchronous way (sometimes a change of setting can trigger a full reindexing of data, this is why there is this asynchronous mechanism). If you wait a bit, the job will be executed and you will see your new settings.

Comment: yep, I removed the highlight params from the query 5 min ago to check this and it worked, thx.